# Is there a "unique factorization theorem" for finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sometimes it is difficult for me to understand what a group seems like.

For example, the dihedral group $D_5$ is easy to visualise when I think it of as a "product" of two cyclic groups $C_2$ and $C_5$.

However, I really don't have an idea how $A_5$ looks like. I know that it is the "half" of symmetry group $S_5$ and has $60$ elements, but that's all I know.

So, is there a way to express every finite group uniquely as a product of "easy" groups? (I didn't want to say simple instead of easy because simple already have a definition)

Comment: I don't think there is a theorem that characterizes groups in that way. But in case of abelian groups; they can be written as direct product of cyclic groups.

Comment: $D_5$ is not quite a direct product like that, but you are on to something.  It is a semidirect product of the groups you mention.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Comment: The nearest you have is the [Jordan-Holder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series), which says every finite group can be built, in some sense, from simple groups.  But unfortunately that makes $A_5$ one of your "easy" groups.

Comment: @mt_ That was what I was going to say ... Here the irreducible objects are the simple groups (some of which are far from simple). But the means of combining the component parts are also more complicated - semidirect products do not always work.

Comment: All finite solvable groups (and solvable is necessary) have a *Sylow basis*, this is a set of pairwise permutable Sylow subgroups of G, one for each prime divisor. Sylow bases are unique up to (simultaneous) conjugacy, so there is a kind of unique factorization for solvable groups. But this leaves open the problem of understanding $p$-groups on one side and non-solvable(especially non-abelian simple) groups on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CPM writes, its not true that $D_5$ is a direct product of $C_2$ and $C_5$, as I'm sure you're aware. Nonetheless, you may be interested in the [directly indecomposable groups](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Directly_indecomposable_group), which can be thought of as being "easy" groups. It is clear that for every finite group $G$, there exists a finite multiset of directly indecomposable groups whose product is $G$. There is also a uniqueness result, the [Krull-Remak-Schmidt theorem](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Remak-Schmidt_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Since a finite group G can be seen as a subgroup of a permutation group S_n and any permutation can be described uniquely as a product of commuting disjoint cycles is this not an irreducible factorization of any element of the group?